# Is thre a way to pass worflow for databricks from airflow with a custom new cluster with DatabricksSubmitRunOperator

Tags: python, json, airflow, databricks, airflow-api

I'm traing to find a way to pass worflow for databricks from airflow with a custom new cluster with DatabricksSubmitRunOperator via the json.
If anyoane has an example with all parameters of how this json should look like i will appreciate.
This is the git for the operator: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/providers/databricks/operators/databricks.py
Thank you!

I've tried to pass a json as in this https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs.html#operation/JobsRunsSubmit but i had 0 results

Comment: please edit post to show what you have tried already